# Android NDK - Using libraries compiled with a different API level

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a group of C/C++ libraries compiled with a standalone toolchain for API 19 and NDK rev 17, is it be possible to use these libraries on a project that uses API 26 (min SDK target 19)?  Or do I need to recompile them using API 26?

In the script, `make_standalone_toolchain.py` ask for the `--api` argument but I am unsure if this is supposed to be the minimum API or the target API used on the project.

Comment: This is how the native platform version is decided when you build with gradle: _"If there exists a platform version for the ABI equal to minSdkVersion, ndk-build uses that version.
Otherwise, if there exists platform versions lower than minSdkVersion for the ABI, ndk-build uses the highest of those platform versions. This is a reasonable choice because a missing platform version typically means that there were no changes to the native platform APIs since the previous available version.
Otherwise, ndk-build uses the next available platform version higher than minSdkVersion."_

Comment: So I don't see any problem with using those libraries if your app's `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher.

Comment: @Michael is there any option I need to set other than specifing the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion on the Gradle?

Comment: If you're talking about what you need to set to control which native platform level you're building for, then `minSdkVersion` should be enough. Of course there are other settings like `targetSdkVersion` and `compileSdkVersion`, but they have no impact on native code as far as I know.

Comment: Just share this link: https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it be possible to use these libraries on a project that uses API 26 (min SDK target 19)?

Yes, it is possible, but, may not be ideal. As seen from below `android-ndk-r17c/platforms` structure:

[image]

**android-ndk-r17c** contains your project minimal API level 19, and this API level only includes TWO architectures, i.e. **arm** and **x86**. This means all your compilation will refer and link with those libraries inside `arch-arm` or `arch-x86` respectively. And note they are 32-bit ABIs. In future, if you have to include the 64-bit ABIs, e.g. `x86_64` or `arm64`, I think you need to recompile your native code at least with `--api 21` (since api 21, NDK starts to support 64-bit ABIs).

If your android projects using your native shared libraries in question are compiled with `minSdkVersion 21` or above 21, I would suggest you compile your native code using the standalone toolchains with `--api 21`. Because there is no added value to set `--api 19`.

**References:**

- [Ensure that your app supports 64-bit devices](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#does_your_app_include_64-bit_libraries)
- [Standalone Toolchains](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/standalone_toolchain)

Comment: It's not relevant that API 19 didn't support 64-bit. 64-bit libraries can be built against a different API level than the 32-bit libraries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is okay to mix and match libraries with different `minSdkVersion`s (the only SDK version that is relevant to the NDK). This is actually the default configuration whenever you target something other than the NDK's minimum supported API level, because the C++ standard library is built against the minimum supported version.

The only thing you need to keep in mind is that the highest `minSdkVersion` is the `minSdkVersion` for the whole app. If you have a library built for 19 and a library built for 28, the oldest Android version that app will run on is 28.

(To be clear, that is per-ABI. If you target 21 for 64-bit and 16 for 32-bit, the 32-bit app can still be run on 16.)