# E/Unity: Unable to find main

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I am using Unity in combination with a custom NDK-Library, inside my app.
My problem is that if I try to start the Activity hosting Unity, the process always crashes with the message:

> E/Unity: Unable to find main

and a alertBox from Unity:

Title:Failure to initialize!

> Message: Your hardware doesn't support this Application

After some trying arround, I got the solution that I have to add the following into my gradle File:

```
android{
    ...
    defaultConfig{
    ...        
        ndk {
               abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

after doing this Unity runs without Errors, but when I start an Activity housing my own NDK-Library it crashes with the Error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/de.biosign.daimlerhrv-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libMyLib.so"
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:972)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
        at de.biosign.sessioncomponents.session.RunningSession.<clinit>(RunningSession.java:34)
        at de.biosign.mvc.session.sessionController.SessionController.<init>(SessionController.java:63)
        at de.biosign.biofeedbackunity.BiofeedbackUnity.onCreate(BiofeedbackUnity.java:109)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1063)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

Has anyone got a solution for this problem and can give me a Hint.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to add the following to my Android.mk:
(See also at https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk)

```
TARGET_ARCH : armeabi-v7a x86
```

so my libs became, generated for this architecture, it runs again beside Unity,
According to some posts newer Versions of above 2017.4 Unity already support 64 bits, but for my work am using 5.6, so can use this.

For others using 2017.4 or above there is the link:
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit#unity_developers

Answer (score 2):

According to your error logs

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: ...... /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64, /system/vendor/lib64

It looks your device is 64-bit. But your `abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'` is only for 32-bit.

So, the possible solution to your problems may be as below adding 64-bit ABIs into the `abiFilters`:

```
abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
```

Cross check:

- [Android NDK - Using libraries compiled with a different API level](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54432673/8034839)
- [How do we identify libraries build with NDK is 64-bit supported?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54504068/8034839)

Comment: I have tried it not, my NDK works with this configuration, but unity doesn't run

Comment: Is it possible to define different abiFilters for unity and my NDK?
I have already tried to seperate them by putting them into different Modules and define different abiFilters via the gradle File, but without success

Comment: For one application, you can only choose to have one consistent ABI supports, e.g. if you choose to let your 64-bit devices fall back to use 32-bit shared libs, then **ALL** your shared libs have to be 32-bits. You cannot expect some libs be 64-bit while some other libs be 32-bit because 32-bit and 64-bit have different address resolution.

Comment: So, try to remove all the libs for 'arm64-v8a' and 'x86_64' for both your NDK projects and the unity libs.

Comment: Can I configure ndkBuild to create 32bit Versions instead of 64bit Versions, it seems that Unity isn't available for 64bit

Comment: sure, you can only use the 32-bit version of shared libs