# Which versions of the Android NDK support 64-bit architectures?

Tags: android, android-ndk

According to the Android Developer website, [Starting August 1, 2019, your apps published on Google Play will need to support 64-bit architectures](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit).

Is there any clear documentation that specifies which Android NDK versions support 64-bit architectures? Or a better question is, what tools can I use to find this out for myself (someone will say Google :D)?

Comment: Links that may be relevant to you: [how-do-we-identify-libraries-build-with-ndk-is-64-bit-supported/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54475476/how-do-we-identify-libraries-build-with-ndk-is-64-bit-supported/54504068#54504068)

Comment: [android-ndk-using-libraries-compiled-with-a-different-api-level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54421427/android-ndk-using-libraries-compiled-with-a-different-api-level/54432673#54432673)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [NDK Revision History](https://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/revision_history):

> *Android NDK, Revision 10 (July 2014)*
>
> **Important changes:**
>   * Added 3 new ABIs, all 64-bit: arm64-v8a, x86_64, mips64.